# Using companion object to return an instance of the class in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

```
Android Studio 3.0 RC2
Kolin 1.1.51
```

I creating an Android App, and I want to return the instance of the class that extends Application and access the equivalent you would do using a static in Java.

```
class BusbyMoviesMainApplication : Application() {
    companion object {
        private val instance: BusbyMoviesMainApplication = BusbyMoviesMainApplication()

        @JvmStatic
        fun getBusbyInstance(): BusbyMoviesMainApplication {
            return instance
        }
    }
}
```

I am accessing it like this. However, getCacheDir returns null

```
BusbyMoviesMainApplication.getBusbyInstance().getCacheDir()
```

I can't see what I am doing wrong.

In Java I have done like this before, which works, I am trying to do the same in Kotlin:

```
public class BusbyMoviesApplication extends Application {
    private static BusbyMoviesApplication mBusbyMoviesApplication;

    public static BusbyMoviesApplication getInstance() {
        return mBusbyMoviesApplication;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mBusbyMoviesApplication = BusbyMoviesApplication.this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Kotlin code, you're calling the constructor of the `Application` subclass directly instead of letting the framework create it for you. You could instead do what you did in the Java code, and initialize the `instance` property in the `Application`'s `onCreate` method (plus I shortened the getter a bit):

```
class BusbyMoviesMainApplication : Application() {
    companion object {
        private lateinit var instance: BusbyMoviesMainApplication

        @JvmStatic
        fun getBusbyInstance() = instance
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this
    }
}
```

---

Based on the discussion in the comments below, this would perhaps be a more idiomatic solution for the getter:

```
class BusbyMoviesMainApplication : Application() {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        lateinit var instance: BusbyMoviesMainApplication
            private set
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the hell do you explicitly generate the setter instead of let kotlin generate it for you?

Comment: It was the simplest way to maintain Java compatibility and let Java code access the instance as `BusbyMoviesMainApplication.getBusbyInstance()`. I assumed this was required from the `@JvmStatic` in the question. Of course if you're only using Kotlin, you could make the `instance` property public and get rid of the getter, and then access it as `BusbyMoviesMainApplication.instance`.

Comment: Kotlin will generate the getter anyway. For java interop, you can make it public and add `@JvmStatic` annotation to get `getInstance()` method

Comment: You're right, I was avoiding this because it would also generate a setter, since `lateinit` properties always have to be `var` to be assignable. I just realized that this can be solved by `private set` to it though. I'll edit the answer in a moment.